# Block other workstations on WAN network accessing LAN of pfSense

Tags: esxi, pfsense, exchange-2007

I am using VMware ESXi to create a network with a test domain running Exchange 2007.

I'm using pfSense as the firewall between my physical network (which I am using as the WAN) and the VM internal network (which isn't connected to physical ports) which is the test domain's LAN.

Everything is working fine. The LAN is using `192.168.1.x` addresses and I am routing traffic through our network which is `192.168.62.x`

Users on our network are now getting security alerts in Outlook for the test Exchange server (currently they show as for mail.contoso.com as I haven't configured Exchange).

I need external mail access to this test domain so that I can prove failover techniques but I'd like to block the other network users seeing the domain.

Currently I can ping the firewall and servers on our `62.x` network from my VMs too (not so much of a problem but it would be nice if these were blocked from each other).

What rules can I set in pfSense to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Domain controller

```
LDAP (389/3268 TCP/UDP), Kerberos (88 TCP/UDP), DNS (53 TCP/UDP), RPC netlogon (135 TCP)
```

Exchange 2007 Hub Transport server

```
SMTP (25/587 TCP) SSL
```

Exchange 2007 Mailbox server

```
 RPC MAPI (135 TCP)
```

SMTP Relay servers (in a perimeter network)

```
 SMTP (25,995 SMTP TLS)
```

Exchange 2007 Unified Messaging server

```
 SMTP (25,995 SMTP TLS)
```

Exchange 2007 Mailbox server

```
 RPC MAPI (135 TCP), many dynamic*
```

Exchange 2007 Unified Messaging server

```
 VoIP (TCP 5060,5061 SSL,5065,5066)
```

Public Folders (hosted by an Exchange 2007 Mailbox server)

```
 RPC MAPI (135 TCP)
```

Public Folders (hosted by an Exchange 2007 Mailbox server)

```
 RPC MAPI (135 TCP), many dynamic*
```

Exchange 2007 Client Access server

```
 80/443 TCP SSL
```

Outlook 2003 client

```
 RPC over HTTP (80/443 TCP)
```

Outlook 2007 client

```
 RPC over HTTP (80/443 TCP)
```

Other clients (POP3/SMTP/IMAP4)

```
 POP3 (110/995 TCP), IMAP (143/993 TCP), see too 995 SMTP TLS
```

/

```
* By default, "many dynamic ports" is the port range 1024-65535.
```

[Understanding the Ports That Are Used by Exchange 2007 in a Mixed Environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789693%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

It may change, if setup RPC range port:

Setup RPC range port in server and clients workstation!

[How to configure RPC dynamic port allocation to work with firewalls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596/en-us)

Additional:

[Restricting Active Directory replication traffic and client RPC traffic to a specific port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224196/en-us)

Configuring Domain Controller Ports
[Windows 2000/2003 Replication through a Firewall](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/paulbergson/archive/2012/05/15/windows-2000-2003-replication-through-a-firewall.aspx)

To test were more meaningful use these wonderful free Architecture magazines and papers:

[The Architecture Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb410935.aspx)

[MSDN Architecture Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/cc511514)

[Architecture Blog](http://www.microsoft.com/architecture/Profiles.aspx)

[Microsoft Download Center: Architecture](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=Architecture)

[Microsoft Download Center: Architecture diagrams](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=architecture%20diagrams)

[Microsoft Download Center: Architecture poster](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=architecture%20poster)

Well, get some magically materials Microsoft Airlift.

## pfSense:

[Adding Rules With easyrule](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Adding_Rules_With_easyrule)

[pfSense: Configuring NAT and Firewall Rules](http://www.packtpub.com/article/pfsense-configuring-nat-firewall-rules)

[Example basic configuration](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Example_basic_configuration)

[pfSense: Important CLI commands](http://www.linuxnet.ch/pfsense-important-cli-commands/)

Comment: That is very useful information thanks, I now need to know where in pfSense to place the rules, as the rules I have set don't seem to work (I used a block all as a test).

Comment: @neildeadman Ok, see updated. May bee it work.